# Filter data using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the data i want to get currency EUR value not USD how it is possible.

```
 [{"currency":"USD","amount":3260},
  {"currency":"EUR","amount":"320.00"}]
```

my code is

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
          <h5 ng-repeat="balance in balances">
            {{balance.amount | currencyFilter:balance.currency}} ({{balance.currency}})
          </h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display only data where currency not USD :

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <h5 ng-repeat="balance in balances | filter:{ currency : '!USD' } ">
    {{balance.amount}} ({{balance.currency}})
  </h5>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yes thats great where is my mind so silly thanks Alanib

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <h5 ng-repeat="balance in balances" ng-if="balance.currency !== 'USD'">
            {{balance.amount}} ({{balance.currency}})
    </h5>
</div>
```